# How To Center Javascript Onclick In Center of Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I need help centering my javascript pop up in the screen. When I scroll down my screen and click the link that activates the onclick popup it comes up at the top of my page (where I can't see the popup). How can I get this to pop up in the center of my screen even when I'm scrolled down.

```js
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add css to position the popup/modal to the center of the page. Something like this:

```
.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e9ftscov/

Source and Explanation of the CSS code I used: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Answer (score 0):

You should use position:fixed in your popup parent.
Try with this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display="block";document.getElementById('light').style.position="fixed";document.getElementById('fade').style.display="block";">
```

If not you can use css stylesheet:

```
.light{
 position:fixed;
}
```